# Mass Updating prices in a 2000 articles sql table

Tags: database, laravel, edit, bulk

I'm completely new in the e-commerce - SQL world and I'm seeking some expert opinion.

I just built an book store e-commerce. The table has 2000 book records and the user until now has edited the prices in Excel with formulas where he bulk edits hundreds (or thousands) of prices at once, associating the isbn number of his catalog's books with the isbn numbers of the spreadsheets the editorials sent him.

Now they'll sale books online with this e-commerce and i was wondering what is the best way i can get them a tool to solve that problem since it's insane for them to edit the prices one by one. 
I built a really reactive form with javascript events but still they're still editing one by one which isn't a solution.

The site was built with laravel 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the excel file and update the records using book ISBN. Just read from excel and update in sql